# Moving circle in html website

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to create this moving circles like in photo:

[image]

Is it javascript or smth else ? I see canvas in their html.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do it using css animation and also canvas. Even the ancient GIFs can achieve this.

Comment: if you search on codepen you will find enough examples. For example [this one](https://codepen.io/jedtrow/pen/azWywW).

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions for this. You can take a look at [d3js](http://d3js.org). It's a javascript framework to create SVGs (including animation). There are greate functions to manipulte circles ([like this](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/69808ec7ec07542ed7df))